# XML как добавить новые узлы в определенное место

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xml

**Структура XML файла:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DOCTORS>
    <DOCTOR>
        <surname>Никитина</surname>
        <name>Авготья</name>
        <patronymic>Петровна</patronymic>
        <profession>Терапевт</profession>
        <category>1</category>
        <PATIENT>
            <surname>Понамарев</surname>
            <name>Олег</name>
            <patronymic>Игнатьевич</patronymic>
            <date_birth>12.02.1997</date_birth>
            <category>Инвалид</category>
            <NOTES>
                <date_note>01.03.2020</date_note>
                <diagnos>ОРВИ</diagnos>
                <price>560</price>
            </NOTES>
        </PATIENT>
        <PATIENT>
            <surname>Николаев</surname>
            <name>Георгий</name>
            <patronymic>Николаевич</patronymic>
            <date_birth>17.11.1985</date_birth>
        </PATIENT>
    </DOCTOR>
    <DOCTOR>
        <surname>Романовна</surname>
        <name>Светлана</name>
        <patronymic>Николаевна</patronymic>
        <profession>Дерматолог</profession>
        <category>6</category>
    </DOCTOR>
</DOCTORS>
```

К примеру я хочу добавить пациента доктору 'Романовна Светлана Николаевна'
Сейчас я добавляю вот таким образом:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("DOCTORS"));
// ...
doc.Element("DOCTORS").Element("DOCTOR").Element("DOCTOR").Add(patient);
```

**Вопрос:**

> Есть ли другой способ добавления ? В частности хочу избавиться от
>   повторяющихся слов `.Element("DOCTOR").Element("DOCTOR")`

Comment: Ей богу, научитесь делать сериализацию и забудьте про работу с XML документом напрямую...

Comment: А лучше вообще выбросьте XML на помойку. Здесь он точно не нужен, ибо то, чем Вы занимаетесь, напрямую является обязанностью баз данных

Comment: Все основные поставщики баз данных поддерживают XML в своей базе данных: Oracle, Microsoft, IBM, PostgreSQL, Marklogic, Snowflake и т. Д. Это эра NoSQL баз данных тоже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это то же самое с использованием LINQ-to-XML.
Я добавил проверку, если пациент уже существует.

> c#

```
void Main()
{
    const string inputDocument = @"e:\temp\doctors.xml";
    const string doctorSurname = "Романовна";
    const string PATIENTS = "PATIENTS";
    const string PATIENT = "PATIENT";

    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(inputDocument);

    // создаем нового пациента
    XElement patient = new XElement(PATIENT
        , new XElement("surname", "Иванов")
        , new XElement("name", "Иван")
        , new XElement("patronymic", "Петрович")
        , new XElement("Birthdate", DateTime.Parse("1989-01-23")));

    // находим нужного доктора
    var ourDoctor = xdoc.Descendants("DOCTOR")
        .Where(x => x.Element("surname")
        .Value.Equals(doctorSurname)).FirstOrDefault();

    // и добавляем пациента к доктору
    if (ourDoctor != null)
    {
        // Проверка существования тега ELEMENTS
        if (!ourDoctor.Elements(PATIENTS).Any())
            ourDoctor.Add(new XElement(PATIENTS));

        // Проверьте, если пациент уже существует, чтобы избежать дубликатов
        bool duplicatePatient = false;  
        foreach (var elem in ourDoctor.Element(PATIENTS).Elements(PATIENT))
        {
            duplicatePatient = XNode.DeepEquals(elem, patient);
            if (duplicatePatient)
             break;
        }

        // пациент не существует
        if(!duplicatePatient)
        {
            ourDoctor.Element(PATIENTS).Add(patient);

            // сохраняем в файл 
            xdoc.Save(inputDocument);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Оригинальный (у автора вопроса) xml кривой, в нем нет тега `PATIENTS`.

Comment: Да, он вернул XML обратно, как это было в его первом посте. Он не понял вашего объяснения там, что этот тег нужен.

Comment: Ну, значит он сам себе злобный буратино 

Answer (score 0):

Берем класс `XmlDoctorsService` из прошлого моего ответа на ваш [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1093213/222542)

Вот нужный вам доктор в файле выглядит так

```
<DOCTOR>
    <surname>Романова</surname>
    <name>Светлана</name>
    <patronymic>Николаевна</patronymic>
    <profession>Дерматолог</profession>
    <category>6</category>
    <PATIENTS />
</DOCTOR>
```

Пишем такой не хитрый код

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string file = @"D:\docs.xml";
        var xmlDoctors = new XmlDoctorsService();

        //получаем коллекцию докторов
        List<Doctor> doctors = xmlDoctors.GetDoctors(file);

        //создаем нового пациента
        var patient = new Patient
        {
            Surname = "Иванов",
            Name = "Иван",
            Patronymic = "Петрович",
            Birthdate = DateTime.Parse("23.01.1989"),
        };
        //находим нужного доктора
        var docRoman = doctors.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Surname.Equals("Романова"));
        if (docRoman != null)
        {
            //и добавляем пациента к доктору
            docRoman.Patients.Add(patient);
        }

        //сохраняем в файл
        xmlDoctors.SaveDoctors(file, doctors);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

В итоге получаем так

```
 <DOCTOR>
<surname>Романова</surname>
<name>Светлана</name>
<patronymic>Николаевна</patronymic>
<profession>Дерматолог</profession>
<category>6</category>
<PATIENTS>
  <PATIENT>
    <surname>Иванов</surname>
    <name>Иван</name>
    <patronymic>Петрович</patronymic>
    <date_birth>23.01.1989</date_birth>
    <category />
    <NOTES />
  </PATIENT>
</PATIENTS>
```